# How to create a PutInfluxdb processor in Apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to push data into Influxdb through Apache nifi, but there is no processor for influxdb in nifi by default. Based on my search I found that new processors can be created in Apache Nifi. So, kindly help me out to know how to make a `PutInfluxdb` processor in Apache nifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache NiFi 1.6.0 release includes InfluxDB bundle. It has `PutInfluxDB` processor. ([NIFI-4289](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4289))

For your question on creating custom processor, please take a look at the following links:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4318/build-custom-nifi-processor.html
- http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/
- https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/02/04/custom-processors-for-apache-nifi

Comment: I am using Apache nifi 1.4.0 ...how can I update it to Apache NiFi 1.6.0 ?? @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman

Comment: This guide may be of help: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/1.x.0+to+1.x.0+Upgrade